# CSS : Rendered width is not exactly while word-wrap

Tags: css

As width:'auto', the width of the parent div depends on its children. But it leaves some visible space on the right side while word-wrap. How can I get the exact content width like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbLUA.png)?

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    Central Central CentralCentral
  </div>
</div>


.parent{
  border:1px solid red;
  white-space:normal;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  width:auto;
  max-width:155px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/remila_antony/LdLuqhtz/

Comment: But this way you are setting the width to '155px' implicitly

Comment: Hi @MrLister I couldn't use <br> as the content may vary :(

Comment: _“As width:'auto', the width of the parent div depends on its children”_ - no, it doesn’t - the div is a block element, and so width:auto means full available width. Only your max-width limits the width of the div here.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no CSS only way to achieve what you want.
If there is, maybe with some clever use of flex boxes, which I am not exactly a guru on yet, I'd be delighted to hear it!

Meanwhile, here is a little JavaScript ditty that does what you want. It decreases the width until the height grows (caused by the words wrapping more), then increases the width a bit.

```js
var p = document.getElementsByClassName('parent')[0];
var w = p.clientWidth, h = p.clientHeight;
do p.style.width = (w -= 10) + 'px'; while (w >= 10 && p.clientHeight <= h);
do p.style.width = (++w) + 'px'; while (p.clientHeight > h);
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 155px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>Central Central CentralCentral</div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that this is not foolproof though; the only reason it works is because you allow the text to break mid-word. Otherwise, it would have failed if you would remove the first space from the content.